# Is there an equivelant for MediaScannerConnection but for other files? i.e text/csv files

Tags: java, android, csv, download

I'm creating a .CSV file and saving it to /sdcard/Download but the file never shows up in the 'Downloads' app.

I've tried all the different ways of using MediaScannerConnection/Intents but as far as I can tell they are specifically for media files and so a CSV file is probably of no use to it, so it is getting ignored.

Is there an equivelant to MediaScannerConnection that isn't specifically for media?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to create a mediafile in the Download folder? Does it display then? Just make the extension .jpg instead of .csv. But if your file is not downloaded then why put it in a download folder?

Comment: I've created the file and put it in as a .csv and it doesn't work. I'll try doing is as .jpg as you suggested as a test, that'll hopefully tell me if I'm going wrong somewhere else. That said, it won't be a long term solution obviously. The file is exported CSV data that the user would then email on to someone else so I figured putting it to downloads would be the best solution. If there is somewhere more appropriate I'd appreciate it

Comment: If the KitKat write restrictions are permanent then you better export to your external files dir as under KitKat thats the only place you can deposit them. Future proof.